# How do I get this to use the correct elsif statement?

Tags: ruby

The answer ends up being half of what it should be. It is using a lesser rate than it should, and I don't know why. For example, 45 books at a weight of 1.5 is being multiplied by rate = 0.20, but it be multiplied by rate = 0.50.

I have tried adjusting .to_i and .to_f, among a variety of other things.

```
puts "Please enter the price of one book." #Asks for book price
price_input = gets #Stores book price
puts "Please enter the weight of one book." #Asks for book weight
weight_input = gets #Stores book weight
puts "Please enter the quantity of books." #Asks for number of books
quantity_input = gets #stores number of books
price = price_input.to_f
weight = weight_input.to_f
quantity = quantity_input.to_f

#Determine shipping cost per pound
total_weight = quantity * weight
total_weight = total_weight.to_f

if (total_weight < 2)
     rate = 0.10
   elsif ((total_weight >= 2) or (total_weight < 10))
     rate = 0.20
   elsif ((total_weight >= 10) or (total_weight < 40))
     rate = 0.30
   elsif ((total_weight >= 40) or (total_weight < 70))
     rate = 0.50
   elsif ((total_weight >= 70) or (total_weight < 100))
     rate = 0.75
   else (total_weight >= 100)
     rate = 0.90
end
rate = rate.to_f
ship_cost = total_weight * rate.to_f
ship_cost = ship_cost.to_f

#Determine discount based on quantity
if ((quantity >= 0) or (quantity <= 9))
  discount = 1
elsif ((quantity >= 10) or (quantity <= 39))
  discount = 0.9
elsif ((quantity >= 40) or (quantity <= 69))
  discount = 0.8
elsif ((quantity >= 70) or (quantity <= 99))
  discount = 0.7
else (quantity >= 100)
  discount = 0.6
end

discount = discount.to_f
d_cost = quantity * discount.to_f
d_cost = d_cost.to_f

#Display final costs
puts "Subtotal: #{price * quantity}"
puts "Shipping: #{ship_cost}"
puts "Discount: #{d_cost}"
puts "Total cost: #{(price * quantity - d_cost) + ship_cost}"
```

The results I'm getting should be double than what they are.

Comment: To set off blocks of code indent 4 or more spaces or select the unindented code and click on `{}` above the editing box. To set off code within text surround it with backticks (e.g., \`[1,2,3]\`). (To show those backticks I had to excape them. Had I not done so you would see `[1,2,3]`.)

Comment: As this code is written it's either incomplete or non-functional. For example: `price = price_input.to_f` but `price_input` is never defined. If you want a float from input `gets.to_f` does the trick.

Comment: When writing code like this, consider writing methods instead of just slapping the code right in the middle. That weight-rate calculator should be inside something like `def rate_for_weight(total_weight)` and then you can simplify how that's implemented.

Comment: I've edited it properly and have included the rest of what I've written (although, I apologize if it's now too much).

Comment: It'd benefit you a lot to use a debugger gem such as byebug to step through your code. However at minimum you can put a bunch of `puts` statements along the way to inspect the values

Answer (score 0):

I thought it would perhaps be most useful to suggest how you might reorganize your code, but if this answers your specific question all the better. If it does not I believe someone else will do so before long.

Your use of case statements to determine the applicable rate and discount is fine, but here is an alternative way of doing that.

```
RATES     = [[2, 0.10], [10, 0.20], [40, 0.30], [70, 0.50], [100, 0.75],
             [Float::INFINITY, 0.90]]

DISCOUNTS = [[9, 1.0], [39, 0.9], [69, 0.8], [99, 0.7], [Float::INFINITY, 0.6]]
```

The `RATES` array gives the shipping cost per book depending on the maximum weight of all books. If that weight is less than `2` (pounds, say), the costs is (in dollars, say) $0.10 per book. If the total weight is greater than `2` but less than `10`, the unit shipping cost is $0.20, and so on. The unit cost is `$0.90` if the total weight is `99` pounds or more. (Why these amounts are increasing I cannot say.)

Similarly, if fewer than `9` books are ordered the discount per book is `1%`; if at least `9` but less than `39` ordered, the discount per book is `0.9%`, and so on. (I'd expect the discount percentages to be going up, but who am I to say.)

Now let's ask the user some questions. We might create a simple method to reduce the amount of repetitive code.

```
def ask(str)
  print str
  gets.to_f
end
```

```
price    = ask("Please enter the price of one book: ")  #=> 43.12
weight   = ask("Please enter the weight of one book: ") #=> 1.45
quantity = ask("Please enter the quantity of books: ")  #=> 30.0
```

The quantities on the right are the three values I entered. Next compute the subtotal:

```
subtotal = price * quantity
  #=> 1293.6
```

Since `price` and `quantity` are floats, `subtotal` will also be a float. (In fact, if `price` were a float and `quantity` were an integer, `subtotal` would still be a float.)

Now let's compute the shipping cost and discount. Again, to avoid repetitive code, let's create a simple method:

```
def rate_or_discount(arr, amt)
  arr.find { |k,v| amt < k }.last
end
```

```
total_weight = quantity * weight
  #=> 43.5 
rate = rate_or_discount(RATES, total_weight)
  #=> 0.5
ship_cost = total_weight * rate
  #=> 21.75
```

Do you understand why `0.5` was returned for `rate`?

Now compute the discount and then the total cost.

```
discount = 0.01 * rate_or_discount(DISCOUNTS, quantity)
  #=> 0.009000000000000001 
total_cost = (1 - discount) * subtotal + ship_cost
  #=> 1303.7076
```

Note that `(1 - discount)` is a float since `discount` is a float.

We can now display the values of interest.

```
puts sprintf("Subtotal: $%.2f", subtotal.round(2))
Subtotal: $1293.60

puts sprintf("Shipping: $%.2f", ship_cost.round(2))
Shipping: $21.75

puts sprintf("Total cost: $%.2f", total_cost.round(2))
Total cost: $1303.71
```

See [Kernel#sprinf](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf) for explanations of the formatting codes I used.

One could instead write (note the newline character):

```
printf("Subtotal: $%.2f\n", subtotal.round(2))
Subtotal: $1293.60
```

Had I instead written:

```
puts "Subtotal: $#{subtotal.round(2)}"
```

the line

```
Subtotal: $1293.6
```

would have been displayed, which has the trailing zero lopped off.

See also [Enumerable#find](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) and [Float#round](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Float.html#method-i-round).